# How to remove custom nav bar back button

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am adding some subview to main view controller. When I add one of these subview, I create a custom back button so that it will go back to main view controller, not the prior view controller in the navigation stack. I can add it programmatically but I can't seem to figure out how to delete it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
    func createCustomBackButton() {

              self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
              let customFont = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(26.0)
              UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: customFont], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

              // customBackButton is a property I set for UIBarButtonItem
              customBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "<", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "back:")
              self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBackButton
        }


           func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
              UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
                 self.containerView.alpha = 0
                 }, completion: { finished in
                    self.view.sendSubviewToBack(self.containerView)
                    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false

                    // what do I do on this line to get this to disappear or set to nil??
                    self.customBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.z, target: self, action: nil)

                    // clears out prior view that was there to free up memory
                    for view in self.containerView.subviews {

                       view.removeFromSuperview()
                    }
              })
           }
```

Comment: `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil` should do what you want.

Comment: Just what I needed. If you submit this as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks for the help @Caleb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil` will reset the `leftBarButtonItem` back to the default.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an unwind segue. If you're using storyboards, drag from the "destination viewcontroller" to the thing that looks like a sideways share button (exit button) of the VC you want unwind from. Name it whatever you'd like, we'll call it "unwind"

and then call in the same VC:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwind", sender: self)
```

in the VC you want to unwind back to:

```
@IBAction func unwindToMapSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. So basically I'm creating custom functionality in that back button so that it will basically resign the subviews when hitting the custom back button. However if no subviews are displayed, I want the standard back button to operate and go to prior VC on the stack. I just need to figure out how to remove this custom back button once I have resigned the subview. Thanks again!

Comment: In your method for `createCustomBackButton` you can do a bool of something like if subViewsExist { backButton } else { otherBackButton } rather than doing it in your `back` selector